# Error while installing Windows Server 2008 64 Bit version from a USB Flash Drive

Tags: windows-server-2008, 64-bit, usb-boot

I am trying to install Windows Server 2008 64 bit version from a USB flash drive. I have made the USB drive boot-able by looking at this [link](http://jesscoburn.com/archives/2007/10/15/installing-windows-2008-via-usb-thumbdrive/)

I have copied the content of the Windows Server 2008 64 bit iso image to the USB drive.

Now I have made changes in BIOS setting to prioritize the USB drive ahead of the hard disk.

Installation was started, but after entering or ignoring product key; A pop up has been raised saying the following

**Windows Cannot open the required file H:\Sources\Install.wim. Make sure all the files required for installation are available, and restart the installation. Error code: 0X80070000D**

But the file *Sources\Install.wim* is existing in the USB drive.

Please help me to resolve this issue. I would be happy to provide any further info, if required.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Run md5sums on the USB drive to verify that your files are valid.  Are you sure your DVD media you copied from was in good condition, perhaps you need try a different disk, or if you are using a volume licensing, download a clean copy from MS.

Comment: Ok I will check that. Can you, please let me know, if there will be any issues with FAT32 and NTFS file system of the USB drive.

Answer (score 1):

There is a much easier way to copy the contents of a Windows ISO to USB, go to http://emea.microsoftstore.com/UK/en-GB/Help/Windows-7-USB-DVD-Download-Tool and download the Windows 7 USB DVD Download Tool. As the name suggests it's designed for windows 7 but, as Server 2008 R2 and Windows 7 are essentially the same OS, it works fine.

Please note, though, that at the moment there is an issue with installing from USB using UEFI boot loader, this only works when installing using BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I hope that the issue is with the iso file which is corrupted. I have downloaded the Windows server 2008 r2 enterprise version from Microsoft site and everything worked fine.

Also, one more observation. **Please download the iso from Microsoft site using Internet explorer(using java based download manager), with Firefox the file got corrupted.**

Hope this is helpful for others